# K-means finds a singleton cluster when I standardize features (Wholesale customers dataset)

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, data-cleaning, dimensionality-reduction

I am studying the [Wholesale customers dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wholesale+customers). Running the elbow method I find that k=5 seems to be a good number of clusters. Unfortunately, when I standardize my features I get a singleton cluster, even with several inits. This does not happen when I don't standardize.

I know that standardization of the features is an often-asked question, however I still don't understand if that's good practice or not. Here I standardize because the variances of some features are quite different. If it's a bad idea here, can you please explain why?

Here is an example of MDS visualisation of K-means result. As you can see, at the bottom left of the picture there is point which has its own cluster (it has a unique color). Is it because it's an outlier? Should I remove it by hand before running K-means?

[image: MDS viz of k-means result]

Here is a MWE if you want to rerun the experiment yourself. Please don't hesitate to be straightforward if I somehow made a mistake.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
df = pd.read_csv("./wholesale-dataset.csv")
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.values[:,2:])
km = KMeans(5)
km.fit(X)
mds = MDS().fit_transform(X)
fkm = plt.figure()
fkm.gca().scatter(mds[:,0], mds[:,1], c=km.labels_)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with k-means producing Singleton clusters.

When you have outliers in your data, making such clusters is likely improving the SSE objective of k-means. So this behavior is correct.

But judging from your plot, I'd argue that your correct k is 1. There is one big blob there, some outliers, but not multiple clusters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a MDS visualisation; I think it collapses the different clusters because of the outliers. The elbow method suggests taking a few clusters. I should try for other criteria though.

Comment: The elbow method is random. The axes have different scales. Don't use it. MDS on the other hand is approximately distance preserving. You can see that the clusters are not separated.